# PHP error when trying to upload .mp3 files via Media Library

Tags: uploads, media, errors, media-library, fatal-error

When I'm trying to upload a sound file (mostly .mp3's) via the media library, I get the following errors:

```
Warning: require(/path/to/website/wp-includes/ID3/getid3.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /path/to/website/wp-admin/includes/media.php on line 2997

Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required '/path/to/website/wp-includes/ID3/getid3.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in /path/to/website/wp-admin/includes/media.php on line 2997
```

First I thought there is a permission error, but after an hour of checking every file/folder permission, I didn't find anything out of order (files 644, folders 755).

I also tried to search on google of course, but I didn't find any forum topics related.

Any ideas?

Comment: What version of WP is this? Because I can't find any require statement for `getid3.php` in `media.php` in the current version. Have you checked the file `/path/to/website/wp-includes/ID3/getid3.php` is there?

Comment: WP version is 4.1.1. Yup, the file is there, and the path is correct as well.

Comment: Oops. Sorry. My bad. I was in `wp-includes/media`. Well it can't open this file. Either the path is wrong or the permissions for that file are wrong. There is nothing else I can come up with.

Comment: Found the problem. It was a problem with my host, in the path the ID3 folder name was uppercase, while on the server for some reason it was lowercase, this is why it didn't find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the problem. It was a problem with my host, in the path the ID3 folder name was uppercase, while on the server for some reason it was lowercase, this is why it didn't find it.

Comment: Thanks. This helped me find that on Debian, it assumes it'll be installed into `/usr/share/wordpress` and so it symlinks everything back to ../../../ but since I have a copy of that install in /var/www (because LSB standards...) I needed to change it to an absolute symlink e.g. `ln -s /usr/share/php/getid3 /var/www/example/net/wordpress/wp-includes/ID3`.  FWIW, I think it's silly that this was closed as off-topic as the choice of library providers and how to package Wordpress is very development-related.